# How to retrieve and display data from another table

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables

Table (1): 'games' with column names of 'games_id', 'home_team_fk', 'away_team_fk', etc.

Table (2): 'teams' with column names of 'teams_id', 'teams_name', etc.

'home_team_fk' = 'teams_id'

Currently my statement will only retrieve the 'teams_id'. This is my current code. I want to generate an SQL statement that will display the 'teams_name' instead of the 'home_team_fk'.

```
<?php
$season = $_GET['season'];
$stmt = $DBcon->prepare("SELECT * FROM games WHERE games_season = '$season'");
$stmt->execute();
?>

<?php if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) { while($row=$stmt->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>   

<?php print($row['home_team_fk']); ?> vs <?php print($row['away_team_fk']); ?>

<?php } } else { ?>

No games recorded yet.

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Look into using JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query will return the home team name and away team name for a given game season. It uses the teams tble twice to get the team name for home and away teams.

```
select t1.teams_name as home_team_name,
            t2.teams_name as away_team_name
from games g
join teams t1 on g.home_team_fk = t1.teams_id
join teams t2 on g.away_team_fk = t2.teams_id
where g.games_season = ???
```